# ERROR TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_NativeBlobUtils.default.getConstants') while integrating "react-native-pdf"

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-pdf

```
 ERROR  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_NativeBlobUtils.default.getConstants')
 WARN  Module RNFetchBlob requires main queue setup since it overrides `constantsToExport` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

Getting this above error in iOS while integrating `react-native-pdf` into my react native project. Do I missed anything?

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.0",
"react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
"react-native-pdf": "^6.6.2",
"react-native-blob-util": "^0.17.3",
```

Xcode - 14.2 (14C18)

iOS SDK - 16.2

Answer (score 1):

It works for me when changing

```
import ReactNativeBlobUtil from 'react-native-blob-util'
```

to

```
import ReactNativeBlobUtil from 'rn-fetch-blob'
```

inside your "react-native-pdf" library index.js file.